# Problema para descargar url de una imagen almacenada en Firebase Storage

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Después de mucho buscar me decidí a preguntarles porque no logro encontrar la respuesta a mi problema. Estoy haciendo una aplicación para mostrar la información de los productos que tiene un negocio utilizando Firebase. En "Database" tengo toda la información del producto (nombre, descripción, etc.) y en "Storage" tengo almacenado una imagen relacionada a cada producto.

A través de un Adapter logro bajar la información de "Database" y disponerla en un GridView. El problema lo tengo cuando quiero asociar la imagen a la información del producto a través de la Url de Firebase. Según estuve viendo (y lo probé manualmente) para hacer esto debo conseguir la Url del estilo "https://....." y lo que logro obtener es una Url del estilo "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn@42041500" que no me está sirviendo para traer la imagen desde Firebase.

No se si es importante, pero las imágenes las he subido yo directamente al "Storage" y no a través de la app.

Les dejo los códigos para ver si alguno me puede ayudar.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!!!

**AccesoriosActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productos_grid_view);

    // FirebaseDatabase
    FirebaseDatabase accesoriosDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference accesoriosDatabaseRef = accesoriosDatabase.getReference().child("accesorios");

    // FirebaseStorage
    final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

    // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
    ArrayList<AccesoriosObject> accesorios = new ArrayList<>();
    final AccesoriosAdapter adapter = new AccesoriosAdapter(this, accesorios);
    GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // tomar info desde firebase
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // This is the method that gets called whenever a new message is inserted into the messages list.

            final AccesoriosObject accesorios = dataSnapshot.getValue(AccesoriosObject.class);

            final String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            Task<Uri> downloadUrl = storageRef.child("accesorios_imagenes/" + key + ".jpg").getDownloadUrl();
            Log.v("downloadUrl", String.valueOf(downloadUrl));

            accesorios.setImagenProducto(String.valueOf(downloadUrl));

            adapter.add(accesorios);
        }
```

**AccesoriosAdapter**

```
(...) // Find the ImageView in the child_list_view.xml
    ImageView imagenImageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.gridView_imagen_producto);
    // Get the version name from the current Word object and set this text on the Nombre del Producto
    assert currentAccesorio != null;
    Glide.with(imagenImageView.getContext()).load(currentAccesorio.getImagenProducto()).into(imagenImageView); (...)
```

**AccesoriosObject**

```
(...) public AccesoriosObject(String nombreProducto, String descripcionProducto,
                        String precioProducto, String unidadProducto,String imagenProductoUrl,
                        String tipoProducto) (...)
// Tomar la Url de la imagen del Producto.
    public String getImagenProducto() {
        return mImagenProductoUrl;
    }

    // Set url de la imagen del producto
    public void setImagenProducto(String imagenProductoUrl){
        this.mImagenProductoUrl = imagenProductoUrl;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Si usas `downloadUrl.toString()` en vez de `String.valueOf(downloadUrl)` obtienes el mismo resultado?

Comment: Hola! A. Cedano, gracias por tu respuesta. Sí, obtengo el mismo resultado: V/downloadUrl: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn@41fb0ce0

Comment: La verdad que no lo sé, me surgió cuando quise utilizar getDownloadUrl()

Comment: Pablo, según la doc, para obtener la URL debes hacerlo dentro de un método `onSuccess`, ya que se trata de una llamada asíncrona. [Prueba como se indica en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419#download_data_via_url).

Comment: La documentación la estuve viendo, y estuve probando de implementarla, pero me quedé trabado cuando dice: // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'

Comment: Estimado!! Logré conseguir la Url formato "https" utilizando "String downloadUrl = uri.toString();" Ahora solo me queda que aparezca la imagen en el GridView. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Son algo especiales en la documentación . Se trataría de obtenerla como lo tienes en tu código pero dentro de un método `onSuccess`

Comment: Me alegro. Para lo otro revisa la documentación, vi una forma muy fácil de hacerlo , o sea, poner una imagen en un layout. Pero ya debo irme... Revisa la documentación ... Saludos.

Comment: Solucionado!! Gracias por la ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cedano pude encontrar el camino a mi respuesta y solucionar mi problema.

Lo que sí es lento para descargar las imágenes. Porqué podrá ser??

El cambio que hice fue el siguiente en **AccesoriosActivity**:

```
storageRef.child("accesorios_imagenes/" + key + ".jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        Log.v("downloadUrl", downloadUrl);
                        assert accesoriosObject != null;
                        accesoriosObject.setImagenProducto(downloadUrl);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Prueba a hacerlo con `Glide`, es la forma que [recomiendan en la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419#downloading_images_with_firebaseui)

Comment: Hola de nuevo! Sí, eso también lo vi. Pero tuve problemas con el ".into". Cómo hago por que ahi debería ir un "imageView" específico y yo tengo que meter las fotos en un adapter.

Comment: Pablo no lo he probado, pero se supone que el `Adapter` usará algún layout en el cual deberá haber un `imageView`, debería ser ahí donde deberías ponerlo.